# How can I save the RAW rtp output file by ffmpeg

Tags: stream, ffmpeg, local-storage, rtp

I have a problem that to save Output RTP as a file. 
(Is that a possible? Am I Right?)

Trans-coding goal as below: 
1. Save the RTP stream to file in local storage using FFMPEG. 
2. Input is file. 
3. Output is RTP stream file.

I`m using that.

> ./ffmpeg -re -i ../Video_Sample/03.Fashion_DivX720p_ASP_87s_1000k_720p.mp4 -c:v libx264 -b:v 1000k -preset superfast -an -f rtp -y test.rtp

But I got a message like that :

Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument

How can I fix it?

Answer (score -1):

RTP is the Real-time Transport Protocol and not a file.

If you want to stream your mp4 file you could do it as followed:

```
ffmpeg -re -f mp4 -i ../Video_Sample/03.Fashion_DivX720p_ASP_87s_1000k_720p.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -b 1000k -preset superfast -an -f rtp rtp://hostadress:port
```

Did you mean rpt (Report File) file?

Comment: The question is asking how to save the RTP bytestream to a file, which e.g. is useful as sample data when developing video software.